# Rails I18n auto translate base on key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

If I just do

```
= t('.foo')
```

in a view file and I have no this translate in locale, it just capitalize the key and the result will be `Foo`

But why it's not happens in other places such as input attributes? This example show translate missing error:

```
= f.submit t('.foo')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t is a view helper (see doc here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate)

If the key exists, it will just output the translated string, but the value returned for a missing translation key will be `<span class=“translation_missing” title=“translation missing: .foo”> Foo </span>`.

In the `= t('.foo')` case, you don't see anything special, because the span is inline with your text, and you don't have any dedicated formatting (but have a look, the span will be there in case of missing translation). But in the `= f.submit t('.foo')` case, this  becomes the text on the button, so you notice it.

Comment: But what I should do for english translate? Keys such as `foo: foo` looks stupid.

Comment: You could perhaps create your own t helper for those cases. But that would be a work only relevant for one-word expressions in english